# PHP RegEx with or without trailing slashes

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

**My goal:**

To capture the last part of a URL whether there is or isn't a trailing slash, without the trailing slash being a part of the string on a URL similar to the one following:

```
http://foo.com/p/dPWjiVtX-C/
                 ^^^^^^^^^^
               The string I want
```

**My issue:**

Every way I try only allows for a trailing slash and not for a url without a trailing slash or makes the trailing slash be contained in the string I want.

**What have I tried?**

**1.**
***I have tried to add a slash to the end:***

```
  $regex = "/.*?foo\.com\/p\/(.*)\//";
  if ($c=preg_match_all ($regex, $url, $matches))
  {
    $id=$matches[1][0];
    print "ID: $id \n";
  }
```

This results in error when I don't have a trailing slash.

**2.**
***I have tried to add a question mark:***

```
  $regex = "/.*?foo\.com\/p\/(.*)[\/]?/";
```

This results in the slash, if exists, being inside my string.

**My question/tl;dr:**

*How can I build a RegEx to not require a slash, yet keep the slash out of my preceding string?*

Comment: btw, why not use explode ("/", $url) ? You can extract the last value of the array which should be your target.

Comment: I need to verify that it is a proper url for the site too

Comment: You can still check for a trailing slash and append (or remove) it depending on your needs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `.*` is greedy by default, so if it can "eat" the slash in the capturing group, it will.

To make it not greedy, you need `.*?` in the place of the `.*` in your capturing group. So, your regex will be:

```
$regex = "/^.*?instagram\.com\/p\/(.*?)[\/]?$/";
```

Comment: Seems the non-greedy question mark as forced my RegEx to not catch my ID at all.

Comment: Ah yes, my mistake. I've edited to add starting and ending characters.

Comment: The seems like the most practical solution to solve an issue like this. You did, however, put the ^ and $ outside of the slashes, though.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this to capture all characters except the trailing slash in your group:

```
$regex = "/.*?instagram\.com\/p\/([^\/]*)/"
```

Or alternatively, you can use a non-greedy quantifier in your group, you'll have to specify a trailing slash or the end of the string (or some other terminator) in order for the group to capture your id:

```
$regex = "/.*?instagram\.com\/p\/(.*?)(?:\/|$)/"
```

Answer (score 2):

Something you might try perhaps:

```
([^\/]+)\/?$
```

[Demo on regex101](http://regex101.com/r/vY6jF9)

EDIT: Huh, you should have mentioned you need to check the site as well, since you put `foo.com` in your first example string... (and re-edited your question after that...).

You can use this instead to check the site:

```
^.*foo\.com.*?([^\/]+)\/?$
```